# How to create a gate with functionality CCX(a,b,b)?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, gate-synthesis

Can we create a Controlled gate with below functionality?

if {a==|1> && b==|1>} then {qc.x(b)}

Basically, a CCX gate but the output Qubit is actually one of the input Qubits. Apparently, In ccx/mct repetition isn't allowed!

Please do let me know. TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. It wouldn't be reversible. It sends both a=1,b=1 and a=1,b=0 to a=1,b=0.